# Form with validation won't submit on Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

Been dabbling with jquery and mobile and finding that my form validation works 95% of the way on mobile (fine on desktop). What I mean by that is that my code(below) does check to see if the inputs have a value and if not returns an alert. If they all have values then it submits. However when all the inputs are valid my submit button does not work.

I thought is might be the onsubmit="return false" in the form tag, but removing it did nothing. Really stumped by this and would love some experience form jquery experts. ( I have looked at other question on the site but none seemed to help fix my problem)

The jquery code is below, and i have put the whole form in a jsfiddle. What am I missing, thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/wgw3p9ee/1/

```
function vForm() {
$('#fSubmit').click(function () {
    if (0 === $('#fname').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your First Name.');

    } else if (0 === $('#lname').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your Last Name.');

    } else if (0 === $('#address').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your Address.');

    } else if (0 === $('#city').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your City.');

    } else if (0 === $('#mailState').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your State.');

    } else if (0 === $('#zip').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Zipcode.');

    } else if (0 === $('#email').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Email.');

    } else if (0 === $('#phone').val().length) {
        alert('Please Enter Your Phone Number.');

    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing some loose closing tags.

```
   </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="liNav">
        <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="fSubmit" onclick="vForm();" />
</form>
```

You could replace these lines with this:

```
<div class="liNav">
    <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="fSubmit" onclick="vForm();" />
</div>

</form>
```

There's another big issue: every time the submit button is clicked, `vForm()` is called. `vForm()` instantiates a click handler for the submit button every time the submit button is clicked - this is why nothing happens the first time you click submit.  You only need one click handler to make things work, so the `function vform() {` bit can be removed altogether along with the `onclick` attribute of the `#fSubmit` element.

Here's a [working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qat14dw8/2/) of what I mean.

Comment: Hi @alex, thanks for the tip, must have copied and pasted wrong for the missing closing tags -- i see that fiddle works, currently the code is in the <head> and still does not work on a mobile phone.. am i missing something

Comment: Does it work on a normal browser?  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Hi @alex, i finally got it to work, there was some little typo i missed, thanks for the help